# How do I edit my function in python such that my output dataframe shows N/A?

Tags: python, pandas, api

[image]

I have defined a function below in python to extract hours of operation based on business_id that I have already retrieved:

```
def hours_operation(business_id):
    day = day_open(business_id)
    start = day_start(business_id)
    end = day_end(business_id)
    day1 = []
    for i in day:
        try:
            value = "start"+str(i)
        except:
            value = 'None'
        day1.append(value)
    dict1 = {}
    for i in range(len(day1)):
            dict1[day1[i]]=start[i]
    start_df = pd.DataFrame(dict1, index=[0])    
    day2 = []
    for i in day:
        day2.append("end"+str(i))
    dict2 = {}
    for i in range(len(day2)):
            dict2[day2[i]]=end[i]
    end_df = pd.DataFrame(dict2, index=[0])
    for i in day:
        start_df['end'+str(i)]=end_df['end'+str(i)]
    return start_df
```

The issue is that my output appears like this:

```
Out[36]: 
  start0 start1 start2 start3 start4  ...   end2  end3  end4  end5  end6
0   1100   1100   1100   1100   1100  ...   2200  2200  2200  2200  2100
```

I like this format, however, in cases where a business works only 4 days a week and not 7. I want it to return start and end as N/A.

This is what my desired output should look like if a business works only 4 days a weel:

```
start0 start1 start2 start3 start4 start5 start6 end1   end2  end3  end4  end5  end6
     0   1100   1100   1100   1100   1100    N/A  N/A   2200  2200  2200  N/a   N/A
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the python tertiary condition statement, like so:

```
dict1[day1[i]]= start[i] if start[i] is not None else 'N/a'
```

this is assuming that `start[i]` is the value of the start time, and that the value you'd like to not output is a NoneType object. If it is 0 or some string, for example, just update the condition in that statement to reflect that. (of course you'll have to the same thing for the end time)

Comment: after the code hits the API if the business does not run for 2 days it doesnt return as "None" its just blank.

Comment: so that may be a string, you can just use `if start[i] != ""` as the condition

Comment: Im getting a name error 
NameError: name 'dict1' is not defined

Comment: well yes, you have to replace your line that looks like `dict1[day1[i]]=start[i]` with the edit I suggested

Comment: I did replace.It is not reurning as N/A though. it is giving same output

Comment: You'll have to determine what is being returned, you can print out typeof(start[i]), and print out what start[i] actually is so you know what youre looking for